# capistrano run internal command using sudo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Our capistrano setup is: ssh with regular user, but deploy to a location requiring sudo permissions to create files.

I want to run the specific capistrano command `run "cd #{configuration[:releases_path]} && #{decompress(remote_filename).join(" ")} && rm #{remote_filename}"` using sudo. Is there a neat way to over ride it?

```
def distribute!
  upload(filename, remote_filename)
  run "cd #{configuration[:releases_path]} && #{decompress(remote_filename).join(" ")} && rm #{remote_filename}"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use the "sudo" function inside capistrano e.g.

```
def distribute!
  upload(filename, remote_filename)
  sudo "cd #{configuration[:releases_path]} && #{decompress(remote_filename).join(" ")} && rm #{remote_filename}"
end
```

Comment: Thanks, can i override the `distribute!` method someway without changing the code? (`sudo cd` dosent work).

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround made it work.

```
task :self_own_dirs do
  sudo "chown -R #{user} #{releases_path}/.."
end
```

`before 'deploy:update_code', 'deploy:self_own_dirs'`